# Windows 10: RunAs requires elevation even when the command prompt is run as admin

Tags: windows-10, command-line, administrator, runas

I have set up an application which has to be run by a normal user, but requires admin privileges. It is stupid, it is a normal application, but it is installs like that. Users are definitely not allowed to be administrator, just run this program with administrative rights.

When I am logged in as normal user, I can select "Run as Administrator" from the start menu, enter admin credentials. Application runs fine.

The recommended way to prepare this, is to create a shortcut with this properties:

```
runas /user:thispc\administrator /savecred /path/to/application
```

The problem is I get an error message

```
The requested operation requires elevation
```

*Despite that I specified the administrator account and enter the correct password.*

Now comes what blows my mind: I log back in as thispc\administrator. I open a command prompt and enter:

```
/path/to/application
```

It runs without a failure, without prompting for credentials. As expected. But now, as still as administrator in the same command line:

```
runas /user:thispc\administrator /savecred /path/to/application
```

Eneter the correct credentials. And I get the same error message about elevation required.

I don't get that. First, when I am an ordinary user, I expect that RunAs runs my application using the admin credentials. It does not.

So to test, I log in and run the command prompt as administrator. I can run the application just like that, but not with RunAs, although I have the full permissions to that application.

Since you here don't have my application, you can reproduce this running c:\windows\regedit.exe. As administrator you can run it. Using RunAs, you will receive the elevation required error message.

If this happens, what is the point of RunAs? It apparently **never** runs, not even run as administrator.

This is a stand-alone, pristine W10 machine. No policies set, no domain policies in effect.

Comment: What you describe is exactly what is suppose to happen.  If you used the built-in Administrator at any point, the default Administrator does not have UAC prompt, that is by design.  However, in this case, your non-privileged user does.

Comment: Why? What is the RunAs command good for then? Besides, like I said, creating a shortcut using RunAs seems to be the recommended way to use admin credentials.

Comment: OK. Now imagine, I want to grant the user the right to run Regedit as administrator. How would I do that using RunAs. (Don't tell me I should not. I won't. I just want to know how. So I could copy that to run the application of interest.)